# Android library providing less native library architectures than the main project

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to integrate the [Polaris Viewer Kit](http://www.polariskit.com/product/demo/list) SDK in my project but I'm stuck because of this error:

```
 Could not dispatch event: class com.myproject.documents.model.callback.DocumentCallback to subscribing class class com.myproject.documents.ui.DocumentListFragment
     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.myproject-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myproject-2/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.myproject-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libEX_Engine7.so"
```

The SDK is providing native libraries only for `armeabi` and `x86` architectures but my project is already providing libraries also for `armeabi-v7a` and `x86_64`.

So I guess that, since the project is providing some `armeabi-v7a` library, the device is expecting to find all the library for that architecture. Is this correct?

Is there anything that I can do to make the device to use `armeabi-v7a` when a library is available and fallback to `armeabi` when is not?

Additional information: I'm developing with Android Studio 2.2 RC2, Gradle 2.14.1 and testing on a Nexus 6 with Android 7 DP5.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything that I can do to make the device to use armeabi-v7a when a library is available and fallback to armeabi when is not?

The system does this automatically. If the device supported armeabi but not armeabi-v7a it would use armeabi.

The problem is that *your app* doesn't support armeabi-v7a since the SDK you're using does not. Unless you can rebuild the SDK for armeabi-v7a you can unfortunately only support armeabi.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. But I'm still not getting why the exception `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is thrown: the `libEX_Engine7.so` file is available inside the `lib/armeabi` folder (I've checked the APK) but the OS is looking only in `/lib/armeabi-v7a`.

Comment: See the other answers here (@mstorsjo's has a workaround). It will only search one of those directories.

Answer (score 1):

The OS will take libraries only from single folder that matches the most.

for example:
if you have

- *armeabi* with **2** libraries
- *armeabi-v7a* with **1** library

when run on **armeabi-v7a** compatible device it will look for folders (in order)

- *armeabi-v7a*
- *armeabi*

and it will found folder right away (*armeabi-v7a*), and will only take that folder in account resulting in found **1** library

more about supporting and selecting of abis: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#am

**ps.** I had some time ago problem, that I were supporting only *armeabi* platform, but one of dependency libraries does supported all abis, resulting in many crashes (Unsatisfied link errors) on non strict armeabi devices

Comment: This is exactly the behavior that I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dan Albert's answer, keep in mind that armeabi and armeabi-v7a are binary compatible. So if the SDK only provides armeabi, you can actually create a new armeabi-v7a directory and copy the armeabi files into it, and it will work just fine. It will just be possibly less efficient than if the SDK had been compiled for armeabi-v7a. (You can't do the same for arm64-v8a or x86_64 though, since those are different architectures than armeabi(-v7a) and x86.)

And put the other way around; if the native code in your own app isn't very performance sensitive (in practice, if it doesn't use a lot of float math), you don't lose much performance by leaving out the armeabi-v7a version and just shipping armeabi, and you'll save some size on the binary.